# Plotting JSON time series data grouped by category with Pandas and Bokeh

Tags: pandas, time-series, categories, bokeh

I have some daily time series JSON data, which covers multiple sites in the same file (example of a single entry from the JSON at the bottom).
I would like to plot these using Bokeh, with the time series for each site (categorized/grouped by "system_name") as a different coloured line on the same plot. How do I get the plot each line? Current approach is trying to use `multi_line` - should it just be `p.line` using the `for` loop?

Guidance/pointers much appreciated.

```
import json
from datetime import datetime
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource


output_file('wyndham.html')


with open('wyndham_data.txt', 'r') as f:
    a = json.load(f)

res = json_normalize(a['features'])
gby = res.groupby('properties.system_name')


for key, item in gby:
    g = item.sort_values(by='properties.date_stamp')       **<<<works to here**
    source = ColumnDataSource(dict(x = g[['properties.date_stamp']], 
            y = g[['properties.energy_prod(KWh)']]))

p = figure()
p.multi_line(x, y, source=source)
show(p)
```

Sample JSON:

```
    {
    "type" : "FeatureCollection",
    "name" : "wyndham-solar-energy-production.json",
    "features" : [
        {
            "type" : "Feature",
            "geometry" : null,
            "properties" : {
                "system_id" : "9386741",
                "system_name" : "Yerambooee Community Centre  ",
                "date_stamp" : "2018-08-01",
                "energy_prod(KWh)" : 51.5,
                "energy_life(MWh)" : null,
                "C02 (Kg)" : 47.41,
                "KWp" : 18.2,
                "performance" : 2.8,
                "lat" : -37.8587717,
                "lon" : 144.7100923,
                "date_installed" : "2017-07-27"
            }

        }, ...
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! To get the best quality answer, try narrowing your scope. A question about how to read json data into pandas is perfect for stack overflow (though there are already a number of questions on the topic). Separately, you can ask about how to create Bokeh charts. A question about the optimal strategy for visualizing this type of data is probably more of a topic for the stack exchange network's [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of trial and error I found a way to make this to work.
(While the code and output themselves are not pretty - it fulfills the purpose of the exercise).

The number of lines and colours exceeded the number of colours in the Bokeh default palettes. The Bokeh.palettes linear_palette function allowed me to set a unique colour shade to each of the 30 lines.

In the question I posted I used a local copy of the downloaded JSON, which I'd saved to a text file. I've added the `import requests` and target URL, in case you wished to run this for yourself. Note that this took about 15 seconds to run on my machine. Imgur link to screenshot: [Wyndham Wind Farm Scheme Daily Ouput Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tgu6C.png).

I also got a `SettingWithCopyWarning`:

> SettingWithCopyWarning: 
>   A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
>   Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
>
> See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
>     site_data['properties.date_stamp'] = pd.to_datetime(site_data['properties.date_stamp'])

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import json
from datetime import datetime
from pandas import json_normalize
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.palettes import linear_palette, Viridis256

URL = "https://data.gov.au/data/dataset/aa75879c-1d3e-4ad2-b331-826032c6b84b/resource/6e309687-023b-436b-9079-582b7e2fb074/download/wyndham-solar-energy-production.json"

r = requests.get(URL)
a = json.loads(r.text)


res = json_normalize(a['features'])
gby = res.groupby('properties.system_name')
sites = res['properties.system_name'].unique()
num_sites = len(sites)

output_file('wyndham.html')
plot_colors = linear_palette(Viridis256, num_sites)
p = figure(width=1800, height=900, x_axis_type="datetime", 
           title = "Wyndham Wind Farm Scheme Daily Power Output")
p.yaxis.axis_label = "Daily Power Output (kW.h)"

count = 0
for key, grp in gby:
    line_col = plot_colors[count]
    g = grp.sort_values(by='properties.date_stamp')
    site_data = g[['properties.date_stamp','properties.energy_prod(KWh)']]
    site_data['properties.date_stamp'] = pd.to_datetime(site_data['properties.date_stamp'])
    site_cds = ColumnDataSource(site_data) 
    p.line(x=site_data['properties.date_stamp'], y=site_data['properties.energy_prod(KWh)'], 
            legend_label=key, line_width = 2, line_color = line_col)
    count += 1

show(p)
```

[Wyndham Wind Farm Scheme Daily Ouput Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tgu6C.png)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this to plot a line:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import json
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import bokeh

with open('1.json', 'r+') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

df = pd.json_normalize(data['features'])
df.index = df['properties.date_stamp']
print(df)
plt.figure()
df.plot()
```

[image: Plot image]

Comment: I was confused by your import of matplotlib?